# "Incorrect information in file" for some tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, owncloud

My ownlcoud server is reporting "Connection refused error". A close inspection by phpMyAdmin showed that some tables in mysql database are corrupted.

```
Code: Select all
    Table                    Op       Msg_type    Msg_text
    mysql.plugin            repair    Error    Incorrect information in file: './mysql>/plugin.frm...
    mysql.plugin            repair    error    Corrupt
    mysql.procs_priv        repair    Error    Incorrect information in file: './mysql/procs_priv...
    mysql.procs_priv        repair    error    Corrupt
    mysql.slow_log          repair    Error    Incorrect information in file: './mysql/slow_log.f...
    mysql.slow_log          repair    error    Corrupt
```

The owncloud db is fine. I do not know how to fix these tables (Google returns very conflicting results and several entries here are not answered). Is it possible to repair them (phpMyAdmin and mysqlcheck could not)? Can I reset this db to start afresh? Thank you.

Comment: this belongs on database admins.

Answer (score 0):

use below query to repair your table

```
repair table table_name use_frm;
```

OR

You need to replace that frm from another one with same table structure.

Comment: I had already tried that:
mysql> repair table plugin use_frm; returns                                           |
mysql.plugin | repair | Error    | Incorrect information in file: './mysql/plugin.frm' |
| mysql.plugin | repair | error    | Corrupt|

Comment: How? The mysql DB is part of the ownCloud installation. I do not know its structure. Where can I find similar table structures to replace the frm files of the broken tables? I tried to find zipped backup files of the DB with no avail, "Repair table plugin use_frm" in mysql, using repair feature of phpmyAdmin, and mysqlcheck all fails. If plugin, procs_priv and slow_log are standard tables with known structures, can I get their frm files from somewhere? I am a novice in mysql field as you can see. All I want is to get my corrupted ownCloud to work. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user1046647 Yes you can replace full mysql database folder with new one with same mysql version. If you have full access to your mysql files then you can do that. One more thing is there only mysql database tables are corrupted or other tables too?

Comment: Hello Miya. Really? Yes, I am a root user on my Raspberry Pi Debian installation. MySql.db is one of the databases (others are owncloud, wordpress, performance_schema and phpmyadmin) within MySql. According to phpmyAdmin, the repair function reports "The storage engine for the table doesn't support r..." messages on all owncloud and wordpress tables but not error messages like the ones above for mysql.db.

Comment: Within mysql db, all other tables return OK after the repair attempt. Only plugin, procs_priv and slow_log tables return "Incorrect information in file: './mysql/table.frm..." messages.

Comment: okay then do one thing rename corrupted tables files e.g. `.frm` with new name and placed new .frm files at the place of corrupted frm files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67416/discussion-between-user1046647-and-miya-g).